# Find possible fearure values to predict a certain outcome

Tags: optimization, prediction

I have a dataset about patients waiting times in a health district. The data is aggregated by health provider, type of medical procedure, urgency of the procedure (3 classes) and reports the n. of procedures done with the average waiting time in a certain period.
Let's define each row of this dataset as `waiting time`.

I have these data for the whole 2018 and for the first 6 months of 2019. so I added two more columns, one for the year and the second for the number of the month covered.

For each `waiting time`, I have a target waiting time which is the global average of a subset of providers. So this target is unique for sub-groups of rows.

Given a ML model to predict the global average, is there a way to estimate a set of possible values for the n. of procedure and average waiting time for the rest of 2019 in order to have a global value at the end of the year which is lower of a defined threshold?

I was thinking about exploring a random grid of values, but I think I need also to give a distribution to these values, in order not to have impossible situations, based on the 2018 data.

Are there standard solutions for this problem (or libraries for R)?

Comment: [Queueing theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory)?

Comment: Nope, these people cannot be modeled as an ordered queue. There's much more variability and complexity here, given by patients preferences, providers organization, etc